# UpdatePanel AsyncPostBackTrigger does Postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, gridview, updatepanel

I've below `design code` containing `updatepanel` to the `gridview` and `buttons` as shown below -

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="scrptmanager" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <div>
        <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnSortValue" runat="server" />
    </div>
    <div class="current-btns" style="float: left !important;">
        <div id="divFitnessSortBy" runat="server" class="fit-sort">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <b>Sort by :</b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Button ID="btnMostRecent" Text="Most Recent" class="button action sortcomments"
                            runat="server" OnCommand="btnMostRecent_Click" CommandArgument="date" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Button ID="btnMostViewed" Text="Most Viewed" class="Comments" runat="server"
                            OnCommand="btnMostViewed_Click" CommandArgument="views" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="clear">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="hr">
    </div>
    <div class="BlogsPostHolderDiv" id="divPagination">
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updtpanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:GridView ID="gvBlogsPost" runat="server" DataKeyNames="PostID" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            AllowPaging="false" Width="100%" OnRowDataBound="gvBlogsPost_Bound" GridLines="None">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <div class="current-articles">
                            <div class="current-thumb">
                                <a id="lnkThumbnail" runat="server" rel="nofollow">
                                    <asp:Image ID="imgThumbnail" runat="server" Height="135px" Width="186px" />
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="current-list">
                                <h2>
                                    <a id="lnkArticle" runat="server">
                                        <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Subject")%></a>
                                </h2>
                                <div class="views-comments">
                                    <h5>
                                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblNewsletterDate" ForeColor="#808080"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "PostDate")%></asp:Label>
                                        <span class="gray">|</span> <span id="spnViews" runat="server"><span>
                                            <%#Convert.ToInt64(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "TotalViews")).ToString("#,#")%>
                                            Views </span></span>
                                    </h5>
                                </div>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblShortDescription" runat="server"><%#DataBinder.Eval (Container.DataItem, "Body")%> </asp:Label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="clear">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="hr">
                        </div>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>

        </asp:GridView>
        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnMostRecent" EventName="Click" />
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnMostViewed" EventName="Click" />
        </Triggers>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>            
    <input type="hidden" id="hdnLastArticle" value="10" />
```

When i `click` on `btnMostRecent` or `btnMostViewed` the page does `postback` which should not be the case...am i missing something here?

**Expected** - When i `click` on any of the given `button` only `gvBlogsPost` `gridview` should be updated without the `whole page postback`

Help and thanks in advance...!

Answer (score 0):

It looks the only thing you have to do is make sure the triggers are in the same naming container.

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.asyncpostbacktrigger.aspx):

> The control that the AsyncPostBackTrigger control references must be
>   in the same naming container as the update panel for which it is a
>   trigger. Triggers that are based on controls in other naming
>   containers are not supported.